# Differential equation system with complex eigenvalues

Tags: complex-analysis, functional-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

I need to solve this equation

$$ x'=x+y,     y'=-2x+3y$$

I get the matrix rigor and the eigenvectors complex $2-i$ and $2+i$.  When I try to apply the eigenvectors associated the solution for $x$ I simply can't find ( I do find the $y$ though).

The solution on the book for $x=e^{2t}(a\cos(t)+b\sin(t))$

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What can't you find? Is it an eigenvector for one of the eigenvalues?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the system:

$$ x'=x+y,~y'=-2x+3y$$

We have:  $A = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 1\\ -2 & 3 \end{bmatrix}$.

As you found, setting up $|A- \lambda I| = 0$ and solving for the eigenvalue/eigenvector pairs yields:

- $\lambda_1 = 2+i, ~v_1 = (\frac{1}{2}(1-i), 1)$
- $\lambda_2 = 2-i, ~v_2 = (\frac{1}{2}(1+i), 1)$

So, for the first eigenvalue, we have:

$e^{\lambda_1 t}v_1 = e^{(2+i)t}\begin{bmatrix}\frac{1}{2}(1-i)\\1\end{bmatrix} = e^{2t}e^{it}\begin{bmatrix}\frac{1}{2}(1-i)\\1\end{bmatrix} = e^{2t}(\cos t + i \sin t)\begin{bmatrix}\frac{1}{2}(1-i)\\1\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} \frac{1}{2}e^{2t}(\cos t + \sin t) + \frac{1}{2} i (\sin  t-\cos t))\\ e^{2t}(\cos t + i \sin t) \end{bmatrix} $

So, our solution can be written as (because we know that the real and imaginary parts are both independent solutions):

$$W(t) = \begin{bmatrix}x(t)\\ y(t) \end{bmatrix} = a e^{2t}\begin{bmatrix}\frac{1}{2}(\sin t + \cos t)\\ \cos t \end{bmatrix} + b e^{2t}\begin{bmatrix}\frac{1}{2} (\sin t - \cos t)\\ \sin t \end{bmatrix}$$

If you want to write these out independently, we have:

- $\displaystyle x(t) = \frac{1}{2}e^{2t}\left( a(\sin t + \cos t) + b(\sin t - \cos t)\right)$
- $\displaystyle y(t) = e^{2 t}(a \cos t + b \sin t)$

Did you swap the your labels for $x(t)$ and $y(t)$?

Comment: @OlindaFernandes: You are very welcome. I would spend time to understand the approach that Babak S. outlined. Regards

Comment: Excellent work, like usual! +1

Comment: +1 for my friend. 23 hours ago we were walking on a same road here. Nice to meet you Amzoti. ;-)

Comment: @BabakS.: Ditto that my good friend! Hope all is well and +1 for your solution too! Regards

Answer (score 2):

Let's rewrite your equations as follows,assuming that $Dx=x',~Dy=y'$:
$$ \left\{
        \begin{array}{ll}
            (D-1)x-y=0 \\
            2x+(D-3)y=0
        \end{array}
    \right.
$$
By solving this homogenous system of equations, we have:

$$ \left\{
        \begin{array}{ll}
            (D-1)(D-3)x+2x=0 \\
            (D-1)(D-3)y+2y=0
        \end{array}
    \right.
$$ which is equivalent to the following system:
$$ \left\{
        \begin{array}{ll}
            x''(t)-4x'(t)+5x(t)=0 \\
            y''(t)-4y'(t)+5y(t)=0
        \end{array}
    \right.
$$ Now, I think you can do the rest.

Comment: $+_+^+ 1 _+^++$